# What are the reason(s) a wireless network's bssid would change

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

What are the reason(s) a wireless network's basic service set identification (bssid) would change?

I'm trying to figure out some bizarre wifi issues I'm having. Apple's wifi diagnostics tool recorded that my BSSID changed four times in under two hours.

The event was raised on my macbook pro, but I'd like to pose the question generally.

Event Type
BSSID changed
The 'info' column all reports the same value though...

Comment: Do you use a common ESSID? E.g., if your access point is named NETGEAR, maybe several other people were too lazy to change the default as well.

Comment: @jjlin I've changed my ESSID from the default. I disabled it just now, and don't see any wireless networks with the same name